# GRASS GIS Encoding

Tags: grass-gis, encoding

I want to know if there is a way to change the default GRASS GIS 7.8.7 encoding (UTF-8) to (ISO-8859-1).

My problem is that I have accent words in my "attribute data" (á,é,í, etc), so when I work with the module "v.extract", and I want to apply the command line "where=Dren_tipo='Río', nothing happens, if I substitute 'Río' with 'RÃ­-o' it work.

I tried to change the 'environment variables' of GRASS GIS, "GRASS_DB_ENCODING" but nothing happens.

Comment: I guess that the problem is within the sqlite backend attribute table. Where did the original data come from? What was the encoding in the original?

Comment: Please also add which GRASS GIS version you are using.

Comment: @markusN My grass gis version is 7.8.7

Comment: @Micha The original shapefile (with the attribute table) is encoding in ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you need to have a *.cpg (codepage) sidecar file together with all the components of the shapefile. You can create this additional file, I believe, with `ogr2ogr` something like:

```
ogr2ogr "input_cp.shp" "input.shp" -lco ENCODING=ISO-8859-1
```

Then import this shapefile "input_cp" (with the correct codepage definition) into GRASS, and check what is in the attrib table (`v.db.select`).

Comment: Hello Micha, I created the .cpg file with the grass gis tool 'v.out.ogr', and then importing the file again, but it did not work.

Comment: Something weird happen, i set the .cpg file as "utf-8", and now the shapefile work with accents words, but grass gis warning me that "incorrect encoding utf-8 is used" and my accents word are with a interrogation icon ("?"), but when i used module "v.extract" with "where=Dren_tipo='Río' it work!. I am really confused.

Comment: OK, so you have the sqlite database (within GRASS) getting the shapefile encoding correct. Now if you need to see this attribute table also in GRASS GUI, then set the encoding of the application. That's under "Settings -> Preferences -> Encoding.

Comment: it did not work =(, i can work with accent words only if i write  "Ã-" instead of í.  There any posibility that my keyboard is typing wrong? like, show me something in the screen and process another?

Comment: I really don't know. (Keyboard mapping is getting out of the realm of GRASS...). If you run `v.db.select` do you see the accented attribute entries correctly?

Comment: Also, what happens in other programs? Can you type accented chars in a text editor and see them properly?

Comment: i upload the file https://www.mediafire.com/file/wu35i0xlbdkff9m/rio_cautin3.rar/file

Comment: My problem is when i want to filter data with SQL commands (e.g. " where=Dren_tipo='Río' " ), if i select the encoding to ISO-8859-1, my accent words are not detected, so nothing is filter (0 returns), if i change the encoding to utf-8, my accent words are sustituted by a "?" symbol, but the filter SQL work correctly.  I used the grass module "v.extract" for filter.

Comment: My other programs work correctly, actually QGIS do the job without problem.